# Updating a table in Oracle based on data from another table and 3 keys

Tags: sql, oracle

All,

Here is my two tables:

Table customer

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Purchases| Age
  John        Rambo         10       55
  George      Washington    17       99
  Eli         Manning       7        35
```

Table client

```
First_Name | Last_Name | Purchases| Client_Id | Date_Added
  John        Rambo         10       4          12-mar-2016
  George      Washington    17       6          20-jan-2016
  Eli         Manning       7        3          10-dec-2016
  Jerry       Seinfeld      4        3          19-mar-2016
```

Desired result

Table customer:

```
    First_Name | Last_Name | Purchases| Age | Client_Id | Date_Added
     John        Rambo         10       55      4          12-mar-2016
     George      Washington    17       99      6          20-jan-2016
     Eli         Manning       7        35      3          10-dec-2016
```

I want to add Client_Id and Date_Added to customer. Lets say I added those columns and now have to devise the update statement. The conditions are if First_Name or Last_Name or Purchases match in both tables, populate customer. Lets just say for arguments sake these fields will always be unique so we just need one to match. How would you do this in oracle? Mind you this would be done for a couple hundred thousand records.

Answer (score 1):

With all your assumptions, saying that you already added the needed columns, you may need a [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/MERGE.htm).

**setup:**

```
create table sustomer(First_Name , Last_Name , Purchases, Age) as (
 select 'John'   , 'Rambo'      , 10 , 55 from dual union all
 select 'George' , 'Washington' , 17 , 99 from dual union all
 select 'Eli'    , 'Manning'    ,  7 , 35 from dual
);
create Table client(First_Name , Last_Name ,Purchases,Client_Id ,Date_Added) as (
 select 'John'   ,'Rambo'      , 10 , 4 , to_date('12-03-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
 select 'George' ,'Washington' , 17 , 6 , to_date('20-01-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
 select 'Eli'    ,'Manning'    ,  7 , 3 , to_date('10-12-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
 select 'Jerry'  ,'Seinfeld'   ,  4 , 3 , to_date('19-03-2016','dd-mm-yyyy') from dual 
);
alter table customer add Date_Added date;
alter table customer add Client_Id number;
```

**MERGE:**

```
merge into customer cu
using ( select * from client) cl
on ( cl.First_Name = cu.First_Name OR
     cl.Last_Name  = cu.Last_Name  OR
     cl.Purchases  = cu.Purchases
   )
when matched then
    update set Date_Added = cl.Date_Added,
               Client_Id  = cl.Client_Id
```

This gives, on your data:

```
FIRST_ LAST_NAME   PURCHASES        AGE  CLIENT_ID DATE_ADDE
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
John   Rambo              10         55          4 12-MAR-16
George Washington         17         99          6 20-GEN-16
Eli    Manning             7         35          3 10-DEC-16
```

Comment: I'm trying this now. Both tables have more than 500,000 records but under a million so hopefully this won't take a crazy amount of time.

Comment: Merge is usually fast. Of course it strongly depends on your tables, indexes, amount of data and so on, like every other statement.

Comment: Still going. I'll just periodically check ever 30 mins and post an update when done.

Comment: Still going. Any idea why it could take this long? I actually updated one column as a test and if I liked what I saw do both but it's still going.

Comment: I stopped it. I decided to run the entire thing with all updates and let it go over night. Even if it works for now thats fine but down the road I need a more efficient method.

Comment: There's no reason why merge should be slower than update. The only way to understand what's happening is examinating the execution plans. Could you please post them for both merge and update. The complete table structure, including indexes, would be useful too.